# What does the app.module.ts file serve for, what should I do inside of it?

Tags: angular, import, angular-services, angular-module

I'm getting used to Angular 2 but I have a few questions concerning the *app.module.ts* file.

- Why do I have to do the imports in this file since I will be doing
  the inputs again in the *app.components.ts* file.

For example: I
   import my custom pipe and then again I have to import it in my
   *app.components.ts* file

```
import { FirstPipePipe } from './first-pipe.pipe';

@NgModule({
     declarations: [
       AppComponent,
       SecondComponent,
       ThirdComponent,
       FirstComponent,
       FirstPipePipe
     ],
     imports: [
       BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), HttpModule
     ],
     providers: [FetchDataService],
     bootstrap: [AppComponent]    })
```

Then I have the

```
imports: [
           BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes), HttpModule
         ],
```

Why do I import some classes and others not?

Why are the providers here, since again, they appear in the    *app.component.ts*

```
providers: [FetchDataService]
```

Basically, I have to rewrite everything in my *app.component.ts* file.

**What is the purpose of the app.module.ts**?

Comment: read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Comment: I have a youtube video that explains this here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o

Comment: @DeborahK tnx for the video.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Modules are a way of organizing and separating your code.  You can have multiple modules and lazy load some modules.

You import any other modules into the `imports` section.

You declare any components in your `declarations`.  Any components used in the routing of that module, must be declared in that module.  If components are used in another module, then you only list them in that other module.

And you provide your services in the `providers` section.

Modules also help control your Dependency Injection...  You can `provide` services at the Component level or the Module level.  Providing services at the Module level create an instance of the service to share across the entire module.  If you provide a service at the Component level, then it is a unique instance for that Component.  It can be best to only provide a service at one level to avoid confusion - either at the module level or at the component level(in each component you need it).  I find that most of the time, for myself, it is best and easiest to only provide services at the Module level.  Same with `pipes` and such, though any component/pipe you make must still be declared in the `declarations`.

Comment: tnx for the global and local service explanation... So basically the imports and declaration in the app.module are shared across the application right?

Comment: Why do i still have to import my service in my local component when I have provided it inside my module.ts?

Comment: You have to import the service in your component for the sake of the compiler.  But you don't need to `provide` the service in the component if it is provided in the module.

Comment: @Tyler Jennings, I would remove the comments regarding injecting services at the component level.  In order for them to be available to the component, they need to declared in the app.module.ts level.  So, it's not possible, to *only* do DI at the component level.

Answer (score 10):

**What is the purpose of the app.module.ts?**

- It is to startup your application, and set the links to your **other modules**.

---

**1 -** Modules are the logic layers of your application. Each module is there to package things logically, so that it's easier for people to understand and maintain your application, made of several modules.
For example, if you are doing a rich application, you should have a **LoginModule**, an **AuthenticationModule**, etc...

**2 -** You need to import things in your module so that Angular knows what it is going to use. Basically, your **LoginModule** will need the Angular **FormModule**, which might not be needed for the **AuthenticationModule**

**3 -** This leads us here : The **AppModule** therefore should only import the others modules it is linked to, and provide the services that will be needed **globally**. Your future **LoginModule** won't need a service to be provided, but the **AuthenticationModule**, which will have an **AuthenticationService** will most probably do.

These are the basics concepts, try reading the official documentation which offers a lot of knowledge about this subject : https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule